# boost serialization omit version for a wrapper

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

How can I tell boost that for a particular structure it should not write/read a class "version" identifier?

I am writing some wrapper classes for serializing some types in a smaller fashion (like a variable length integer). If the wrapper gets a class version written the whole point of the size reduction is lost (it'll end up bigger in most cases).

For example, given `integer a` I'll be replacing this code:

```
ar & a;
```

with this:

```
ar & wrapper(a);
```

I see the `is_wrapper` trait, but I can't really find any docs on what that does, or if it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(wrapper, boost::serialization::object_serializable)
```

It's the [documented way](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#level).

Comment: You don't happen to know the underlying struct code for that, do you? I have a template type and thus the macros don't work.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Had it been any other library I would have recommended you to just dig the macro out, but in boost... *brrr* just thinking about it gives me shivers.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking only after looking at the macro... though I think I have a syntax it appears that deriving from `wrapper_traits` automatically omits the version, so I don't know if I'm correct.